# User_photo permission cannot be added

Tags: facebook

I have a problem with adding `user_photos` permission and sending applications to review.

When I enter the **Permissions and Features** tab, `user_photos` has the status **Approved** and **View** action instead of **Request**

[image: Permissions and Features tab]

After clicking on the **View** option, it moves me to **My Permissions and Features** which looks like this:

[image: My Permission and Features]

Without this permission, my application will be useless. I'm very much counting on your help.

I already wrote on Community Facebook, tried to contact with support and find a solution on the Internet but unfortunately, I couldn't find anything.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions#reference-user_photos says, _“This permission is restricted to a limited set of partners and usage requires prior approval by Facebook.”_ - which means, normal 3rd-party apps can’t just use it like any other permission. (There is not officially documented way to become such a “partner”, usually this means you have to know the right people …)

Comment: @misorude only it's the first time when I've ever had a situation like this. I sent various review applications with this permission and they've always had a positive review. Now I can't even choose it.

Comment: Then you probably submitted those before Facebook changed the availability of this endpoint to approved partners only.

Comment: Do you know when Facebook changed its policy? And how I can become their "partner"?

Comment: No, I don’t know when they changed it. And as a I said, becoming a partner for such things usually has no official application process - this seems to be more of a “you got to know the right people” thing. If you are a big enough player (in terms of revenue you generate for Facebook by booking ads, etc.), then you should probably have gotten a contact person at Facebook assigned that you can talk to about stuff like this. If not, and you are just a small player - then chances of becoming such a partner are probably very very slim.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'll try to make a deal with Facebook.